# How to compile multiple javascript files with Symfony Webpack Encore?

Tags: javascript, symfony, webpack

My question is simple I have a f.js file containing :

```
function f(x) {
    return x
}
```

and a main.js file calling f(1) for example in an alert :

```
alert(f(1))
```

How to configure Webpack Encore in Symfony to make work this dependency between these two files, in other words how to make f defined in main.js ?

Comment: Learn about ES6 modules & `import` / `export`.

Comment: @SLaks Ok I look into this. Thanks.

Comment: Ok I understand `ìmport` and `export`, but now how to import functions from a library ? I want to import `Bloodhound` from typeahead.bundle.js but I got this error : TypeError: setting getter-only property "Bloodhound", and it works without Webpack.

Comment: Finally it works, I just added var `Bloodhound = require('./typeahead.bundle');` in the js file in which I want to call the function.

Answer (score 2):

Inside `webpack.config.js` file, you define scripts and styles to build:

```
.addEntry('script', 'script_to_compile.js')
.addEntry('script2', ...)
```

This will generate a `script.js` and `script2.js`.

It's more common now, to have a single javascript file to download. From a script, to include other Javascript (and CSS!), use webpack module concept: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/modules/

Example, "I want to use pickaday library":

```
const Pikaday = require('pikaday/pikaday');
require('pikaday/scss/pikaday.scss');

$('.picker-date').each(function()
  {
    const $element = $(this);

    new Pikaday({
        field: $element.find('input')[0]
    });
 ....
```

(you can see I can include a .scss style as well). Same thing for image, use `require('toto.png')` to let webpack know you want this image in the build (then use Symfony `asset` Twig function to use it).